# How can I make `.vim/after/ftplugin/markdown.vim` take effect immediately?

Tags: vimrc, filetype-markdown, ftplugin

I change this file, but it seems that I have to restart Vim to make it take effect.

Is there any way to make `.vim/after/ftplugin/markdown.vim` take effect immediately?

I already tried `:source` and `:runtime`, which do not work.

Comment: Can you please [edit] with (1) exacts steps you take, (2) the results, (3) what you expect and how that differs from (2), and (4) any code snippets that are relevant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best option is probably to trigger the autocommands which are triggered when you set the filetype. To do so you can use [`:h :doautocmd`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/autocmd.txt.html#%3Adoautocmd) with the event `FileType`:

```
:doautocmd filetype
```

For example:

- Open test.md
- Type `ia` to insert a `a`
- Edit `~/.vim/ftplugin/after/markdown.ft` to add `inoremap a A`
- Switch back to `test.md`
- Run `doautocmd filetype`
- `ia` will insert `A` instead of `a`

Note that you probably want to add you customization to `~/.vim/after/ftplugin` directory, this will allow to run the built-in ftplugins *and* your own directives instead of overriding the built-in ones (which happens when you use `~/.vim/ftplugin/`

Comment: Thanks, it works.